# Distance and size of everything in Unity Scene way out of proportion

Tags: unity

Using Unity 2021.2

Following some guides I've noticed discrepancies in sizes. Whether it's text, material or something else, nothing matches up.

Making blocks of 9x9x9 units, adding a textmesh pro text item looks gigantic. The example uses font size 36, and fits nicely inside the cub. For me, the text is larger than the scene and I have to zoom out.

Have to reduce the font to 4 to roughly be the same size.

And this happens all the time with various items and sizes.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: It's literally a default install. Absolutely nothing added or changed about default settings. Only package added: TextMeshPro.

Just default settings all the way. No changes made.

The TextMeshPro object is attached to the cube I made and is, at font size 36, far larger than this cube of 9x9x9 units. How can this be?

Also, moving the cube down on the Z axis 4.5 units moves it several times the cube's height. Which is 9 units. Which doesn't sound normal.

Comment: Since we don't know what "some guides" you're following, we don't have enough information here to reproduce the problem and test potential solutions.

Comment: Including how you set up the text would help as well. is it an GUI text? Some overlay? Directly on the blocks? What kind of camera settings are you using?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem you describe where moving a 9x9x9 cube by 4.5 units moves it multiple times its own height. It sounds like you should edit your question to walk us through creating a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. Thar is, list (or show with a screenshot) literally every step required to reproduce this problem in a new, empty project.